# Linear regression composition for time series

Tags: regression, time-series, linear

I am working on a time series data research project and have been struggling with an appropriate approach. I have a response time series $Y$ and several (<10) explanatory time series $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ that are all over the same time frame of the past year.

I want to build a model that uses the $X$'s as features and find the highest correlation of a linear combination ($a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + \cdots$) with $Y$ while being mindful of overfitting.

What would the best approach to this be, and what Python tools/kits can I use to help?

Comment: Linear regression I guess, you are asking explicitly for a linear model

Comment: How do I conduct a linear regression of time series? What tools can I use?

Comment: Are all your series stationary?

Comment: No, they each have mid-high correlation with the response series, which itself is seasonal.

Comment: Series can be seasonal and yet stationary. As rightly pointed out in the first comment what you are looking for is a linear regression. But for the regression to make sense the series should all be either stationary or cointegrated. If neither, then there are other ways to deal with such series.